# unrecognized selector sent to instance when click on UIImageView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to bind the tap event on a UIImageView like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.backgroundImage action:@selector(imageClicked:)];
[self.backgroundImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];
self.backgroundImage.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

And the method is there:

```
-(void)imageClicked:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"image clicked");
}
```

But when i click on the image view, my app crash and i got this stack:

```
[UIImageView imageClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Am i missing something? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s target should be `self` and not the `UIImageView` itself.

Comment: That's correct. I might add that `target` means the class that responds to the selector, not where the gesture will be added. That's why you call `addGestureRecognizer` on your imageview.

Comment: Thanx a million both for your useful infos :)